# Drawing a centrally aligned tree using LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees

I am trying to draw a tree in LaTeX via following code. It works; however, it is always aligned to the left. How I can make it aligned to the centre?

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}}

\begin{forest}
[TP
    [DP [D\\the] [NP [N\\man ]]]
    [T'
        [T\\will ]
        [VP
            [V\\eat ]
                [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

> Note: The code is taken from Alan Munn (Link deprecated; new version [here](https://amunn.github.io/assets/latex/overleaf-trees.pdf))

Comment: There's a new version of the document you link to. I've removed the old one and added a new link.

Comment: Either you have a fairly outdated version of Forest or your settings are not being applied to your trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`align=center` only centres text within nodes. It does not centre the `forest` relative to the page.

A more fundamental problem is that the settings in `.style` will not be applied with current Forest. To see this, try adding, `blue` and notice that your tree stays determinedly black.

Current Forest provides `default preamble` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\forestset{default preamble={for tree={blue,parent anchor=children, child anchor=parent,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    [TP
        [DP [D\\the] [NP [N\\man ]]]
        [T'
            [T\\will ]
            [VP
                [V\\eat ]
                    [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: blue tree]

Obviously, you should delete the `blue` in your real document.

You might, however, want to use

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
```

instead which will apply a nice (for linguistics!) set of defaults to your trees without your having to specify them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
% \forestset{default preamble={for tree={blue,parent anchor=children, child anchor=parent,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    [TP
        [DP [D\\the] [NP [N\\man ]]]
        [T'
            [T\\will ]
            [VP
                [V\\eat ]
                    [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: with <code>linguistics</code>]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The original code was a hack for forest v1 and was needed because Sharelatex was out of date   I forgot that I had that version documented on my web page.

Comment: @AlanMunn Another answer was accepted before I posted this, so I don't know. Ignasi's answer does answer the actual question. It just repeats the no-longer-working hack.

Comment: Thanks @cfr, I also think this is the correct answer (I changed the correct answer to this one)